# Setting up Hudson extracting war file

Tags: java, hudson, war, extract

I am setting up hudson, i have been able to extract the file once, but is there way of dictating where the files from the war are extracted to?

I want the files to be extracted to my H drive but they are by default extracted to c when executing java -jar hudson.war.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score -1):

I have been very silly, having not read the installation guide fully, I didn't realise you can choose a directory when you install as a window service.

Cheers for giving no constructive feedback whoever marked the question as useless!